# Download a list of all Iteration's work items

Tags: iteration, workitem, sprint

**Is there a way in Azure DevOps to see a list of all the work items for an Iteration release that I can download or email to myself?**

I want to generate and download a list of all work items released in a given Iteration (e.g. sprint), and then share that list with the Customer Support/Success teams so they are updated on released bug fixes and user stories.

When I go to "Boards -> Queries" and I query for work items, DevOps pulls work items assigned to the target iteration (e.g. Iteration 91), but won't pull work items assigned to previous iterations that were released in the current iteration (e.g. work items originally from Iteration 89 and 90 that were released as part of the Iteration 91 release).

- Note: if I query for work items for the target iteration *and* previous iterations, DevOps will pull all work items that were released in the previous iterations plus the current iteration, which is not usable information.

When I go to "Pipelines -> Releases" I see the work items that were released, but I can't copy/paste that list of work items, or email that list to myself. The information can only be found in DevOps and can't be downloaded.

When I go to "Boards -> Sprints" I see a list of work items for the current Iteration that I can email to myself, but that list does not match the list from "Pipelines --> Releases" so I am not confident that this is an accurate list.